# Shorter and more Pythonic way to select item from list

Tags: python

I'm looking for a better way to randomly select an item from a list in Python. I've done some research. My goal is to select a random element from the randomName() function.

```
import random

def randomName():
    names = ["Morpheus","Neo","_from_redpills","Agent Smith","Trinity"]
    num = random.randint(0, len(names)-1)
    return names[num]`

for z in range(5):
    print randomName()
```

Comment: Your title was a bit lacking (it doesn't include the word "random"), but a Google search for "I'm looking for a better way to randomly select an item from a list in Python" produces lots of useful results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. Python has a good way to do this with another part of the random module. You can use random.choice(NameOfList). This will pick a random element from the list.

`def randomName():
    names = ["Morpheus","Neo","_from_redpills","Agent Smith","Trinity"]
    return random.choice(names)`